# Map through an array of five circles and highlight the current element being mapped through

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, animation

I have created 5 circles and I need to add an animation to them. I want to be able to wait like half a second on each circle and highlight that one orange so it looks like a progress bar type thing. Currently, I have 5 divs to display 5 circles. I'm not quite sure how to approach this to do the animation, I could use some help. I have posted a screenshot of the 5 circles. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBn39.png) The app is using ReactJS. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should read about css keyframes. That's the simply and good way to make animations without any javascript.

Comment: I'll take a look at it, not familiar with it